# Associating two custom post types

Tags: custom-post-types, cms

I'm trying to a build a system for a client that involves two posts types: "Clients" and "Media Placements." I need a way to associate Media Placements with a particular Client (essentially treating Clients like a category while retaining full post functionality).

Each client needs to have many media placements associated with them, and they need to be easily updated. Also, both clients and media placements need full "Post" capability. Meaning editable with TinyMCE, Queryable, etc.

Does anyone have any idea what the best way to go about this would be? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a neat plugin that might be of use for your task:

[Posts 2 Post](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/posts-to-posts/)

It is capable of establishing relationships between posts and post-types.

Comment: Works like a charm. Great recommendation!